# Is it possible to open X11 application in terminal of a server in linux?

Tags: linux, x11-forwarding

I can launch X11 application through my local machine to X11 enabled server.
e.g. ssh -x  from my localmachine(linux desktop) then launch a installed application from the minimal server.

I would like to know if it's possible to access my installed application directly from my minimal server. e.g. ssh -x ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is useful but better you can use either Xming or Mobaxterm to get an X11 for a linux machine . Ultra VNC/VNC are also some of those kind .